# How do I stop storage containers being emptied when deploying a new version of my strongloop project?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, angular-loopback

I have various storage containers created in `'./client/storage'` in my project.

When I deploy my project these containers are duplicated on the server in `'/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/current/client/storage/'`. If I do some uploads the files are saved on the server but when I deploy a new version the files are removed.

Should I be using `'.git_ignore'` in some way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the project it doesn't overwrites the previous project folder but recreates a new one.
So I dont think `.gitignore` may be the best way to solve this issue but the safest and better way would be to should `create your storage location outside the scope of the main project folder`.

If possible don't store the images in your local filesystem instead fetch it through the Amazon S3 container or some other cloud service. Loopback provide very easy way to handle all this.